# Generating an ID from primary key sequence without adding a row

Tags: postgresql, sequence

I have the following two tables where I store users and their addresses. I have a problem relating to the order in which I receive and can save data from the user. At first the user will supply only the address and then get directed to an external service. To open this service I need to supply my internal user ID. The service verifies their email address and sends me the response.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public."user"
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('user_id_seq'::regclass),
    email character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_cace4a159ff9f2512dd42373760" PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT "UQ_e12875dfb3b1d92d7d7c5377e22" UNIQUE (email)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.adresses
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('address_id_seq'::regclass),
    address character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "userId" integer,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_bec464dd8d54c39c54fd32e2334" PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_35472b1fe48b6330cd349709564" FOREIGN KEY ("userId")
        REFERENCES public."user" (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

- Can I generate the user ID from the sequence in some other way than entering an email in to the table and in the end enter both the ID and the email at the same time?
- Can I save the address in the addresses table referencing a foreign key which has not yet been added to users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this question, I did the following (all of the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5965c107b355a4b3c75f694bd19fa3e7)):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE user_id_seq;
CREATE SEQUENCE address_id_seq;
```

and the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE user_
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('user_id_seq'::regclass),
    email character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_cace4a159ff9f2512dd42373760" PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT "UQ_e12875dfb3b1d92d7d7c5377e22" UNIQUE (email)
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE address
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('address_id_seq'::regclass),
    address character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    user_id integer,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_bec464dd8d54c39c54fd32e2334" PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_35472b1fe48b6330cd349709564" FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES user_ (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

We use PostgreSQL's [`RETURNING`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25220973/470530) clause with a [Common Table Expression](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-cte/) (CTE - aka the `WTIH` clause).

A simple example:

```
WITH insert_user AS
(
  INSERT INTO user_ (email) VALUES ('user1@example.com')
  RETURNING id
)
SELECT *  FROM insert_user;
```

Result:

```
id  email
1   user2@example.com
```

So, we can see that we can obtain the id from the `INSERT` statement withing the `CTE`.

Now, we take this a step further as follows:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
WITH insert_user AS
(
  INSERT INTO user_ (email) VALUES ('user1@example.com')
  RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO address (address, user_id)
SELECT '1, Long Street, Somewhere', (SELECT id FROM insert_user)
COMMIT;
```

We use a transaction - just in case there's a problem in the step from the first `INSERT` to the second.

```
SELECT * FROM user_;
and
SELECT * FROM address;
```

Results:

```
id  email
2   user2@example.com
and
id         address            user_id
1   1, Long Street, Somewhere       2
```

We see that the `user_id` of 2 is in the `address` table - having come from the `INSERT` into the  `user_` table in the `CTE`.

You **have to** `INSERT` a value for the `email` of the user because of the `NOT NULL` constraint in the `user_` table definition! You can remove the constraint, but I see little point in this.

A few points to note:

- you use `CHARACTER VARYING` - PostgreSQL's [`TEXT` data type is better suited for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20334221/470530).
- `COLLATE pg_catalog."default"` is redundant - if not specified, the collation will be the default.
- you use quoted identifiers, i.e. `"userId"` - far better to use PostgreSQL's [recommended naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2878408/470530) and turn this into `user_id` - i.e. snake_case!
- you have the most bizarre names for constraints that I have ever seen!

  `CONSTRAINT "PK_bec464dd8d54c39c54fd32e2334" PRIMARY KEY (id),`

  and

  `CONSTRAINT "FK_35472b1fe48b6330cd349709564" FOREIGN KEY ("userId")... REFERENCES...`

  The only rationale for this is that it's taken from some other system that gives these horrible names. Far better to have `address_pk_id` or something similar (i.e. meaningful). An error message stating that constraint "PK_bec464dd8d54c39c54fd32e2334" has been violated isn't going to tell anyone much! Plus, transmitting that over a phone call is going to be difficult - much better to use a simple name to which users can relate.

## To answer the questions:

### 1st question:

- `Can I generate the user ID from the sequence in some other way than entering an email in to the table and in the end enter both the ID and the email at the same time?`

You could do the following:

```
SELECT nextval('user_id_seq');
```

Result:

```
nextval
      3
```

and then `INSERT` that into the address table along with an address. But, **what's the point?** You have to have some way of relating a given user to a given address - and you do this by wrapping your `SEQUENCE` value within a transaction - first from the `INSERT` into the `user_` table and then using that value from the `RETURNING` clause to create the address.

### 2nd question:

- `Can I save the address in the addresses table referencing a foreign key which has not yet been added to users?`

No! The **whole point** of `FOREIGN KEY`s is so that you **can't** insert anything into the address table that doens't have a valid `user_id` back in the `id` field of the `user_` table.

You **could** drop the constraints and have some ghastly procedural mess to keep track of what had and hadn't been `INSERT`ed where and when - but again, **why?** You database will do all the work of keeping track of all this if you let it!

Comment: The constraint naming is created by the typeorm library, I will check to see if I can manually specify the names. The reason to generate the ID before adding the email is because I need to supply the ID to an external system which will then give me the email and I want the ID in my system and the external one to match